# How to insert Guest Additions CD image when receiving the below error message?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, cd, guest-additions

When I try to insert Guest Additions CD image I get the following in a dialog box: unable to insert the virtual optical disk C:/Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
It’s followed by “details”: could not mount the media/drive ‘C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso

Answer (score 1):

The Guest Additions must be installed in the Guest Machine, so you need to install the Additions in the Guest machine before committing it to the CD.

You cannot install a program by inserting into the CD Image.